# Moving Letters by tobias ahlin used on several Headings

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, while-loop

I'm using this wonderful javascript animation tool by tobias ahlin https://tobiasahlin.com/moving-letters/#11 it is based upon anime.js. And I'd like to use this animation on several h2 tags. This is the code I need to use multiple times:

```
// Wrap every letter in a span
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.ml11 .letters');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/([^\x00-\x80]|\w)/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

anime.timeline({loop: true})
  .add({
    targets: '.ml11 .line',
    scaleY: [0,1],
    opacity: [0.5,1],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 700
  })
  .add({
    targets: '.ml11 .line',
    translateX: [0, document.querySelector('.ml11 .letters').getBoundingClientRect().width + 10],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 700,
    delay: 100
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml11 .letter',
    opacity: [0,1],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 600,
    offset: '-=775',
    delay: (el, i) => 34 * (i+1)
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml11',
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 1000
  });
```

Any suggestion? Thank you very much

Comment: The code you pasted is just a copy of the one in the link you provided. Please post some more detail on what you are trying to achieve. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question in stack over flow.

Comment: Now what is your question about that code?

Comment: did you try it with two `<h2 class="ml5">` in your HTML? if yes, what were the results?